# Check file size of HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

I have a page with a `<source>` for an HMTL5 video player; I need to obtain its file size.

Is it possible to check the size in MB of a video uploaded on the server from a `<source>`?

Does the HTML5 API provide some functions for this? Solutions with PHP or JavaScript are both fine.

Comment: If you can use PHP, you can get the filesize on the server, and pass it on to the HTML, f.e. as a custom data attribute on the source element.

Comment: is the video on your server?

Comment: yes it is on my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the best way to do this would be via a server side script that responds to (say) and Ajax request, reads the size of the file and responds (or depending on how the pages are being generated you could add it as a custom property to the  element when you create the page the only way I can think of to answer your specific question would be to load the file itself via an ajax request and check the size of the respond - see [Why don't all videos load on page in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344690/why-dont-all-videos-load-on-page-in-chrome/14349145#14349145) for an example of how to do that

Comment: Unfortunately i could not upload the files via ajax request, because i would have  to change much of the system of upload. But for moment i have used a check via full system path $fullpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . $path . $file;  $flsize = filesize($fullpath); , and it works..but im not sure is the best solutions.
Anyway thanks for the advice, it's great!

Comment: Your solution - server side - is much more efficient, and will certainly deliver a better user experience.