# Switching html5 videos on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html5-video, videogular

I am trying to make an interactive video app, the concept is simple, when for example video A is playing videos B and C are preloaded in separate video tags this results in seamless video switching(in most cases). The user while watches can chose which route to take (B or C). This works quite well on desktop browsers, the problem arises when viewing the app on mobile devices as they can not preload videos.

Is there a way to make this concept work with seamless video switching on mobile devices? The only solution I can think of is to play the videos, that are meant to be preloaded, in background muted and when the time comes to show the video, to just restart it and bring it to foreground. This surely isn't the best solution (and probably wont work properly :D )

So my question is, can something similar work on mobile browsers and if yes how would you tackle this problem ?

Comment: Probably to play muted videos in background is your best approach. You can also load the videos as a blob and then create an object url that you set to the src video attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344690/why-dont-all-videos-load-on-page-in-chrome/14349145#14349145

Comment: @elecash Thank you responding. I will try to play muted videos in background and see how that goes. The blob approach is a interesting idea   I will have to try that as well, thanks for the link.